# Saving 'float' numpy images

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def save_np_img(np_img, path, name):
    """
    To save the image.
    :param np_img: numpy_array type image
    :param path: string type of the existing path where to save the image
    :param name: string type that includes the format (ex:"bob.png")
    :return: numpy array
    """

    assert isinstance(path, str), 'Path of wrong type! (Must be String)'
    assert isinstance(name, str), 'Name of wrong type! (Must be String)'

    im = Image.fromarray(np_img)
    im.save(path + name)

    return np_img
```

I would like to be able to save images which contain `float` values, just like I can currently save `int` valued-images.

I get a `TypeError` message when I try to save my images which have been transformed through `np.divide(img, 255.)`, and thus when trying to save numpy_arrays which contain floats.

(You can suggest other librairies, too.)

**NOTE:** The values, when not integers between 0 and 255, are floats between 0 and 1. It is crucial for me to remain as lossless as possible. My initial thought was that I could simply use `np.multiply(img, 255)` but I wasn't sure if that would lose some precision (nor if it would return integers, actually).

**EDIT:** Basically, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292141/9768291) method a lossless convertion? That is, if I had a numpy_array of `ints`, divided it by `255.`, and then reconverted into `ints`, am I losing information? If so, how to avoid that?

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: It won't let me save images when the values of the numpy_arrays are floats.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30946248/3954379), maybe is what you need

Comment: What format are you trying to use?  The PNG format can only store integers.

Comment: Which format should I use? I thought I should avoid `JPG` and so that `PNG` would be a good pick. I didn't know it only supported integers. I need to preserve the 3 dimensions of colors (RGB, which I eventually plan on changing to YCbCr).

Comment: PNG supports up to 16 bits per channel.  Scaling up floating point values from the range [0, 1] to [0, 2**16-1] gives a floating point resolution of about 1.5e-5.  You'll lose information in the conversion to integers, but only you can decide if the loss is too  much.  Alternatively, TIFF supports floating point; take a look at the [`tifffile`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) package.

Comment: You start with 8 bits then go to 32 bits then going back to 8 or 16 bits. So there really isn't any guarantee that you don't lose information. But, you can check `all(int((i/255.0)*255)==i for i in range(256))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell With my university courses, I haven't had much time to work on the project much. I think the TIFF solution seems decent, though I'm unsure if anyone can just visualize a TIFF image without installing extra software. The numpy solution probably will not work (for the same reason I just mentioned for TIFF). Sorry for my lack of feedback, I'm very occupied out here. I will try out the TIFF method eventually. My model some times pops out negative numbers as values for the image: is there a way to clip values when saving to TIFF ?

Comment: What packages/libraries besides tifffile support saving floating point images?

Answer (score 11):

You can save and read back `numpy` arrays of floats losslessly and natively without any libraries being required:

```
import numpy as np

# Create 10 random floats in range 0..1 in array "b"
b = np.random.random_sample((10,)).astype(np.float32)

# Save to file
np.save('BunchOfFloats.npy',b)

# Read back into different array "r"
r = np.load('BunchOfFloats.npy')

# Inspect b 
array([0.26565347, 0.7193414 , 0.19435954, 0.58980538, 0.28096624,
   0.88655137, 0.84847042, 0.80156026, 0.94315194, 0.76888901])

# Inspect r
array([0.26565347, 0.7193414 , 0.19435954, 0.58980538, 0.28096624,
   0.88655137, 0.84847042, 0.80156026, 0.94315194, 0.76888901])
```

Documentation is available [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).

---

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments by @WarrenWekesser you could use a TIFF file which can store floats, and even doubles.

```
import numpy as np
from tifffile import imsave

# Generate float data
b=np.random.random_sample((768,1024,3)).astype(np.float32)

# Save as TIF - when reading, use "data = imread('file.tif')"
imsave('result.tif',b)
```

---

Yet another option is a `PFM` file, described [here](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/PFM/) and [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html).

This is a very simple format that you could write and read yourself, and has the benefit that other packages such as **ImageMagick** and **GIMP** understand it, so you could save your data as a `PFM` file and then convert at the command line with **ImageMagick** to `JPEG` or `PNG` for viewing:

```
magick image.pfm -auto-level result.png
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: as part of the requirements, people should generally be able to visualize the image saved on their computer, and as an enormous bonus `matplotlib` should be able to display the saved image. The `np.save` avenue is quite interesting, but can it be visualize directly?

Comment: In that case, you are probably better going with a floating point TIFF - I have added some demo code. **ImageMagick** can still convert and display such TIFFs.

Comment: And should my decision change in case the loaded dataset is already in PNG ?

Comment: It depends on your needs and design. You could check the type of your input array inside your function and switch formats accordingly, by looking at `np_img.dtype`

Comment: Just a small point, but -normalize will clip a the high and low end of the histogram, which is not good if you are trying to visualize your data unchanged. If you want to view it, I would suggest using -auto-level to do the stretch from floats to visual range of integers.

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, yes, that's a better idea and I have edited it in. I was just trying to avoid the inevitable *"my image is black"* issue. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've had a little bit of time to work on this. As suggested ins ome other comments, I tried this and it seemed to work fine: `plt.imsave('my_image.png', image_to_save, cmap=plt.cm.gray)`. Is there anything wrong with it in regards to my requirements ?